# In Ionic How to Bind File Data with request body (How to do multi-part data)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, file-upload, ionic3, ng-file-upload

I am working with ionic3. I want to bind pdfFile as a fileobj: Multipart Data Then username: "abc" and other 2 3 fields.How can I achieve This ?

Can I use input type file or any other thing ?

Comment: I would be better to add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps and let me know the result

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('param1', param1 value);
formData.append('userName', userName);
formData.append('<your param>', <your file>);

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { ----> In case you have multiple files to upload
  formData.append('files', files[ i ]);
}
```